# why it is returning me only [0]

Tags: python-3.x

Why it is the `filter` method below returning `[0]`? I want all values where `y[x] % 1 == 0`

```py
list1=[]
list2=[]
a=0
b=0
c=0.5
d=65
z=0
while a!=100:
    list1.append(a)
    a=a+1

while b!=50:
    list1.append(c)
    b=b+1
    c=c+0.43

while d!=115:
    list1.append(chr(d))
    d=d+1

print(len(list1))
print(list1)

def filter(e,x,y):
    while x != 200:
        if y[x] % 1 == 0:
            e.append(y[x])
        x=x+1
    return e

print(filter(list2,z,list1))
```

Why it is returning `[0]`? I want to return all values those where `y[x] % 1 == 0`

Why isn't the while executing first? It is returning the result of having run the loop only once.

Comment: please format your code correctly, currently it's unreadable

Comment: Did you intend to use y[x] % 1 == 0 which will always be true?

Comment: @Deepstop list contain float and alphabets also i wanna return only integer elements only

Comment: Generates a TypeError when x=150

Answer (score 0):

Use isinstance to test for an integer.

Change

```
if y[x] % 1 == 0:
```

to

```
if  isinstance(y[x], int):
```

But if you want to include floats that have only zeroes after the decimal point, then you need to watch out for slight errors in floating point representation. So in that case...

```
if isinstance(y[x], int) or abs(y[x] - int(y[x])) < .000001:
```

You can pick the very small number to match the precision you are working at. For instance if all your floats are sums of numbers with maximum 2 decimal places, you could use .005